# How to use getid3 if installed with apt-get install getid3?

Tags: php, getid3

I just installed getid3 on my Debian server:

```
apt-get install php-getid3
```

How can I use it on my website?

I have read that I can use it this way:

```
require_once('getid3/getid3.php');
$getID3 = new getID3;
 $path = 'sample.mp3';
$mixinfo = $getID3->analyze( $path );
```

But I don't know where is located `getid3.php` to require it. How can I use this php class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the files that you download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/?source=navbar
In a folder in your web project, then you can use the library with the code, I recommend you to look the examples first.